# Question on finding a solution to 2-d inhomogeneous heat equation with inhomogeneous BC's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Suppose one is trying to solve this equation,

$$ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{q}{\kappa} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} $$

why is it that we seek solutions of the form

$$U(x,t) = \Psi (x,t) + \phi(x)$$

I am trying to understand the underlying motivation for seeking solutions of this form, also, why is it that one cannot directly apply separation of variables to inhomogeneous PDE's. Thanks for your replies in advance.

Edit: if any of you know the physical difference between $\Psi(x,t)$ and  $\phi(x)$, I would very much appreciate it if you could explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{q}{\kappa} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} \tag 1 $$
Try separation of variables : $\quad U(x,y)=F(x)G(y)$

$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^{2}}=F''(x)G(y)\\ \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=F(x)G'(t)\end{cases} \quad\to\quad F''(x)G(y)+\frac{q}{\kappa}=F(x)G'(t)$ 
$$\frac{G'(t)}{G(t)}-\frac{F''(x)}{F(x)}=\frac{q}{\kappa F(x)G(t)}$$

There is a function of $x$ and $t$ in the right hand term which cannot be separated into a sum of two functions, one of $x$, the other of $y$. This makes impossible the separation. The method fails.

So, we seek solutions of the form 
$$U(x,t) = \Psi (x,t) + \phi(x)$$
which transforms the PDE (1) into
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^{2}} +\phi''(x)+ \frac{q}{\kappa} = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$$
Let $\quad \phi''(x)=- \frac{q}{\kappa} \quad\to\quad \phi(x)=- \frac{q}{2\kappa}x^2 +bx+c$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^{2}} = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$$
Try again the separation of variables : $\quad \Psi(x,y)=F(x)G(y)$

$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^{2}}=F''(x)G(y)\\ \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}=F(x)G'(t)\end{cases} \quad\to\quad F''(x)G(y)=F(x)G'(t)$ 
$$\frac{G'(t)}{G(t)}-\frac{F''(x)}{F(x)}=0$$
Now, it is possible to separate 
$$ \frac{G'(t)}{G(t)}=\frac{F''(x)}{F(x)}=\text{constant}$$
and to solve separately the two ODEs.

Comment: Ah, I see. In a physical setting, if there is a source term such as q, what is the physical meaning of the solutions $ \phi(x)$ and $\Psi(x,t)$? Also, does anything change if one sought the steady state solution?

Comment: If it is really your question it should be better to transfer it on https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, I am currently using those equations to model transient heat transfer problem. The reason why I am interested in the physical meaning behind the solutions is because I must take these solutions and apply them to a larger thermoelectric based dynamical system. It would help me draw some conclusions and perhaps make some predictions, do you know what I mean?

Comment: I understand very well. But physical modeling and  interpreting mathematical solutions in terms of physical meaning is no longer mathematics. That is why I think that the right place is better on physical than mathematical stackexchange.

Comment: True, I'll try that.